# What is @angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to explore how angular decorators are declared. I've found a file `@angular/core/src/util/decorators.ts` where `makeDecorator` function is defined. I was thinking that I could debug this file using a browser and provided source maps. However, a browser doesn't load `@angular/core/src/util/decorators.js` file, it loads `@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js` which seems to include files from `@angular/core/src`, including `@angular/core/src/util/decorators.js` file.

So what is `@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js`? Is it a bundle of `@angular/core/src` files?

There is [@angular/core/tsconfig-build.json](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/core/tsconfig-build.json) file that seems to be build configuration file. It seems to have the same structure as `tsconfig.json` file and is probably used by typescript compiler.

Comment: from my basic knowledge of TypeScript and Angular, I would say yes, the core.umd.js is the transpiled version of the /core/*/*.ts files

Comment: Are you trying to understand this from within Visual Studio?

Comment: @PaulStoner, sorry, didn't understand your comment. I'm exporing sources on github and in npm package

Comment: Ah my apologies. I will do some more research

Comment: FYI: [I've added a comment to what I'm assuming was your issue on github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12779#issuecomment-259485883) asking the angular contributors to attend to these kinds of questions on SO, because it seems like a question they would be able to answer more readily than us...

Comment: Yes, I see now. there is a script in the angular root named build.sh the .ts files are compiled by tsc (the typescript compiler) in their respective .js files. It looks like the build.sh script them takes all of those .js files and combines them in the core.umd.js file. Again, my apologies for my misunderstanding. I am somewhat new to Angular 2. But from what I do understand, I like it a lot. Seems easier than Angular 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading some articles on internet, The best I have come up with is umd in core.umd.js stands for universal module definition. So, core.umd.js is nothing but umd version of angular's core.js module.

Now, you may ask what umd is?
As the name suggest it's a universal pattern for writing modules in javascript. It is being done for developers to write code in single agreed-upon way.

For more clarification please read-

1. http://davidbcalhoun.com/2014/what-is-amd-commonjs-and-umd/
2. https://github.com/umdjs/umd